# help with query

Tags: oracle, select

How to list the departments in Oracle's EMP table which have either two clerks or three  managers?

Comment: You're never going to get an answer when you ask a question like this. Is this your first time online? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @calumbrodie - how wrong you are

Comment: @APC indeed! you have to admit - the questions is a tad sparse and the obligitory 'Please Help!' at the end isn't doing them any favors..

Comment: @calumbrodie - the question was understandable even before I subbed it.  Besides it behooves us to be noice to the new folk.

Comment: @APC I didn't say it wasn't understandable. I said it was a poorly formatted question. And I'm not the only person who thought that. I even posted a friendly link for them to read on how to improve their question. Maybe the sarcasm was a little uncalled for.

Comment: Given the latest edit, I think someone should call for help. Luchi is clearly in the midst of a stroke.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways of getting this result.  Here is one solution:

```
SQL> select deptno
  2         , mgr_count
  3         , clerk_count
  4  from
  5        ( select deptno
  6                 , sum ( case when job = 'MANAGER' then 1 else 0 end ) as mgr_count
  7                 , sum ( case when job = 'CLERK' then 1 else 0 end ) as clerk_count
  8          from emp
  9          group by deptno )
 10  where mgr_count > 3
 11  or clerk_count > 2
 12  /

    DEPTNO  MGR_COUNT CLERK_COUNT
---------- ---------- -----------
        30          3           5
        50          4           0

SQL>
```

Here is a slightly different approach:

```
SQL> select * from
  2      ( select deptno
  3         , job
  4         , count(*) as cnt
  5      from emp
  6      group by deptno, job
  7      )
  8  where ( job = 'MANAGER' and cnt >= 3 )
  9  or ( job = 'CLERK' and cnt >= 2 )
 10  /

    DEPTNO JOB              CNT
---------- --------- ----------
        20 CLERK              2
        30 CLERK              5
        30 MANAGER            3
        50 MANAGER            4

SQL>
```